# custom 404 ErrorDocument path not working in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, error-handling, errordocument

I have the below code in .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 400 /abc/404

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/ - [S=2]
    RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?aa=$1&bb=$2 [NE,L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)$ index.php?aa=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

but I am getting the below error whenever i pass a wrong url

```
Not Found

The requested URL /abc/[S=2] was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

if i remove the line `RewriteRule ^/ - [S=2]` then I am getting the below error

```
Not Found

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

When I try `http://example.com/abcd/` I want .htaccess to redirect to `http://example.com/abc/404` which is a page

what mistake am I doing. Please help me.

thanks in advance

Comment: Is `/abc/404` a valid URL? If yes then post your full .htaccess here in your question.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. I updated the question with the full code and I was waiting for your help. I request you if you can help me with the above that will be very great. thanks

Comment: When you directly goto: `http://example.com/abc/404` does it show a page?

Comment: thank you. and yes it does show a 404 page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok replace your code with this code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /abc/404

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^abc/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?aa=$1&bb=$2 [NE,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^abc/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?aa=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

Comment: if you dont mind can u explain me what is happening in the line `RewriteRule ^ - [L]`.. thanks again

Comment: also what is the difference between [^/]+ and (.*). I only knew that (.*) is a wild card and accepts everything..

Comment: About your question 1: it is actually ignoring rest of the rewrite rules for a real file, directory or link. About question 2: not much difference but [^/]+ matches until you hit a / using negation which is safer and easier to read.